# Has Nigel Farage made a statement regarding his MEP pension?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, pensions, ukip

Here's a [cartoon](https://twitter.com/milneorchid/status/894822309952933888) depicting a fictional interview with MEP Nigel Farage.

Interviewer: "Today on Brexit Talk I'm joined by Nigel Farage to discuss the Brexit Bill. Nigel, how much should we pay?"
Farage: "Zero. Sweet F.A. Not a bean. We owe them nothing! We want nothing from them, so they should get nothing from us."
I: "So I assume, therefore, that you'd be willing to forego your MEP's pension?"
F: "Let's talk about immigration."

Has the real Nigel Farage made a statement regarding his own MEP pension?
Is the cartoon a fair or unfair representation of his position?

Comment: http://www.politico.eu/article/ukips-dilemma-pension-or-principles-nigel-farage/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An article in [Politico](http://www.politico.eu/article/ukips-dilemma-pension-or-principles-nigel-farage/) describes the UKIP position:

> Nigel Farage [...] has been an MEP since 1999, [...] he would expect to receive his full pension — 70 percent of his salary, or around €6,000 a month.
>
> UKIP is quite clear that they will fight to keep the EU pensions after the U.K. exits the bloc. A spokesperson said Farage and co “were elected and worked.”
>
> “So why shouldn’t people who were elected and worked not draw a pension?” he said.

So the position of UKIP is clear. Ex-MEPs should be entitled to their pensions regardless of whether the UK is a member of the EU or not, and this money should be paid from the parliament to the ex-mep.

Comment: They worked? Do they actually make that claim? How much time has Farage worked in his MEP job?

Comment: @gnasher729 according to [mepranking.eu](http://www.mepranking.eu/mep.php?id=4525#mep), mister Farage attended 63% of plenary sessions and participated in 38% of roll-call votes. There's more info on the linked page if you're interested.

Comment: This is in contrast to the position that once you are done with an organization you owe them nothing though. In other words it's hard to see how the UK can have no requirement to follow through on their commitments to the EU once they leave but also the EU should be required to follow through on their commitments (ie: MEP pensions).  Basically the question is whether UKIP has a hypocritical position on this.  This is a complete answer but in my opinion the question should also have asked what UKIPs position was on the so called 'divorce bill'.